# How to send SMS via intent but no recipient

Tags: android

I want to send a SMS via intent (thus not requiring additional permission from the app). However, I simply want to pre-populate the body of the SMS and let the user choose/type in the recipient's number. I haven't had much luck with using `sms:` uri because it requires a phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer to my own question. The `sms:` protocol doesn't actually REQUIRE a phone number.

The following code will bring up a chooser for all apps that support sms messages:

```
final Intent textIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("sms:?body=" + YOUR BODY));
startActivity(textIntent);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use below intent for that purpose,

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content"); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems super hacky to be honest, also this launches the default SMS app instead of allowing me to choose which SMS app to use

Comment: I used this in my app...!